# SQL Query (JOIN?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Good afternoon, I would like to have a doubt about a SQL query.

In the example I have three tables:

```
Table A | Table B | Table AB
```

Table `AB` is the junction of Table `A` and `B`.

I would like to know EVERYTHING you have in Table `A` and `B` that you **DO NOT** have in Table `AB`.

Sorry for the english "google translate"

> **[EDIT]**

Following the tips, to have a result with everything you have in Table A and Table B that you do not have in Table AB would be like this?

PS: I can not test now, I'm on the subway

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID 
FROM TABLE A (NOLOCK), TABLE B (NOLOCK)
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE AB (NOLOCK) 
                WHERE A.ID = AB.ID)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE AB (NOLOCK) 
                WHERE B.ID = AB.ID)
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear so I vote unclear what are you asking.

Comment: 1. what do you mean by "junction" of two tables? Is it intersection? 
2. please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :-)

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AB WHERE AB.A_ID = A.ID)`, similar for `B`.

Comment: Are the columns in each table the same, or do they just have common key columns?  If a row is in A but not in B or AB, do you just need the row, or also need to know what tables it is and is not present in?

Comment: Don't use `,` to join tables together.  use `INNER JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` or whatever it is that you need.  It's only been 25 years since explicit join notation was created...

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach to this problem would use `cross join` and `left join`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a cross join
     b left join
     ab
     on a.a_id = ab.a_id and b.b_id = ab.b_id
where ab.a_id is null;
```

Comment: Assumes that it's a key only comparison, may want an all-columns comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I would use left outer join instead of EXISTS, most of the time I find it faster and more readable.

Something like:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_AB ab on ab.ID = a.ID
WHERE ab.ID IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT b.*
FROM TABLE_B b
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_AB ab on ab.ID = b.ID
WHERE ab.ID IS NULL
```